# App is not listed in the Facebook Developer Appeal page, How can I appeal for Facebook Developers Operations Team to enable the app?

Tags: facebook

A alert appeared in the dashboard saying "We've restricted this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies. Read more or appeal". When I clicked "Read more or appeal" the app which is restricted is not appearing in the list. I have checked in the alerts section too which says "App Disabled - URL Compliance" but there is no email or reply link or button to appeal. My concern is how can I appeal for Facebook Developers Operations Team for enabling/activating my app.
[image]
Note: Update the libraries to latest facebook version i.e. v11.3.0 as of today(6th Oct, 2021) and updated Data Use Checkup, privacy policy url, app icon and related necessary documents.